# How do I manage active development on git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've got a git project with 3 git submodules.  Now I'm actively developing (changing code) in all 4 projects, and I normally do it using vim, from the base directory of the main project.

So if I use `git status`, I see the status of just the main project.  If I use `git submodule status`, then I see the commit sha's of the subprojects (unsure why thats everyday useful), if I use `git submodule foreach git status` I see which files have changed, relative to whichever submodule it considered at the time.

So what is considered the easy way to manage this?  Do I really have to change directory into each submodule when I want to commit anything?  How can I commit, from outside of the submodule (`git submodule foreach git commit -m "message" path/to/file/in/one/submodule` would work, but generate multiple errors and feels risky)

I tried `git --git-dir=path/to/submodule {status,diff}` and they worked fine, but `git --git-dir=path/to/submodule commit -m "message" path/to/file/in/one/submodule` doesn't work, and just complains with `fatal: ambiguous argument 'path/to/file/in/one/submodule': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

As it happens each of the submodules is a variant of a sparse checkout of the same project, so there shouldn't be overlap, but I expect there to be many submodules in the future, so is there some way of effectively doing `git submodule command <submodule> git commit -m "" <path>` on a single submodule